# Import class atributes with json

Tags: python, class

I want to know how to import class attributes with json, but I don't know how and every time I try to learn I get confused and it doesn't work. Can anybody give me resources on how to learn this?

Comment: What are you even talking about?

Comment: This question looks more like a collection of buzzwords than a question.

Comment: I want to load a class with a json file and make that class what the json class is

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON file?

Comment: {"name": "Jessie", "Fav-color": "red"}             Stuff like that

Comment: I think @ethan-baker 's answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what your asking, and is that to load a class from a json file?

You can use the json set up like this to load classes.

My class file will be like this:

```
class Player():
    health = 0
    attack = 0
    defense = 0
```

My json file will be like this:

```
{"health": 10, "attack": 5, "defense": 3}
```

My load file will be like this:

```
import classes as c
import json

def load()
    with open('myFile.json', 'r') as pfile:
        jp = json.load(pfile)
        c.Player.health = jp['health']
        c.Player.attack = jp['attack']
        c.Player.defense = jp['defense']
```

This allows you to make the class have the same stats as the json file says.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You'll need to `import json` as well

Comment: True, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I would also instantiate an instance of the class rather than assigning the values the way you have, and you don't need to leave the assignments in the `with open()` indented block :)